# Spliting String and getting appropriate value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a string where `||||` means next to it is the directory. `|||` means the user is allowed to access this directory and `||` means the files allocated to these users follow.

I need to find allocated file names of a specific user from this string. I have tried to split the string and assign values to an array but I am not able to get the result I'm looking for.

This is the string:

> ||||Root|||adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,adil001,kl04707c,km47389,km58184,km61052,kq61023c,adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,||LimitTest_20140528164643.xlsx,testTask2_20140528140033.xlsx,||||1400842226669|||adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,adil001,kl04707c,km47389,km58184,km61052,kq61023c,adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,||LimitTest_20140528164643.xlsx,testTask2_20140528140033.xlsx,testTask1_20140528135944.xlsx,testTask2_20140528140033.xlsx,||||1401191909489|||adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,adil001,kl04707c,km47389,km58184,km61052,kq61023c,adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,adil001,kl04707c,km47389,km58184,km61052,kq61023c,||LimitTest_20140528164643.xlsx,testTask2_20140528140033.xlsx,testTask1_20140528135944.xlsx,testTask2_20140528140033.xlsx,LimitTest_20140528164643.xlsx,

And here is my attempt:

```
function getData() {
    var user = 'km11285c';
    var value = "||||Root|||adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,adil001,kl04707c,km47389,km58184,km61052,kq61023c,adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,||LimitTest_20140528164643.xlsx,testTask2_20140528140033.xlsx,||||1400842226669|||adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,adil001,kl04707c,km47389,km58184,km61052,kq61023c,adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,||LimitTest_20140528164643.xlsx,testTask2_20140528140033.xlsx,testTask1_20140528135944.xlsx,testTask2_20140528140033.xlsx,||||1401191909489|||adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,adil001,kl04707c,km47389,km58184,km61052,kq61023c,adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,adil001,kl04707c,km47389,km58184,km61052,kq61023c,||LimitTest_20140528164643.xlsx,testTask2_20140528140033.xlsx,testTask1_20140528135944.xlsx,testTask2_20140528140033.xlsx,LimitTest_20140528164643.xlsx,";
    var users = null;
    var files = null;
    var Dir = value.split("||||");
    var arrayLength = Dir.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        users = Dir[i].split("|||");
    }

    return users;

}

console.log(getData());
```

and the [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c6dtL/)

Answer (score 0):

I changed your jsfiddle example a bit so maybe you need to change the code here and there, but something like this should work:

```
function buildTree(data) {
    var tree = [];
    var dirs = data.split("||||");
    // Remove the first entry in the array, since it should be empty.
    dirs.splice(0, 1);

    for (var i = 0; i < dirs.length; ++i) {
        var tempArray = dirs[i].split("|||");
        var dirName = tempArray[0];
        var usersAndFiles = tempArray[1];
        tempArray = usersAndFiles.split("||");
        var users = tempArray[0];
        var files = tempArray[1];
        var treeDir = { name: dirName };
        treeDir.users = users.split(",");
        treeDir.files = files.split(",");
        tree.push(treeDir);
    }
    return tree;
}

function getData() {
    var user = 'km11285c';
    var value="||||Root|||adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,adil001,kl04707c,km47389,km58184,km61052,kq61023c,adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,||LimitTest_20140528164643.xlsx,testTask2_20140528140033.xlsx,||||1400842226669|||adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,adil001,kl04707c,km47389,km58184,km61052,kq61023c,adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,||LimitTest_20140528164643.xlsx,testTask2_20140528140033.xlsx,testTask1_20140528135944.xlsx,testTask2_20140528140033.xlsx,||||1401191909489|||adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,adil001,kl04707c,km47389,km58184,km61052,kq61023c,adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,adil001,km11285c,km61052,km61639c,adil001,kl04707c,km47389,km58184,km61052,kq61023c,||LimitTest_20140528164643.xlsx,testTask2_20140528140033.xlsx,testTask1_20140528135944.xlsx,testTask2_20140528140033.xlsx,LimitTest_20140528164643.xlsx,";
    var tree = buildTree(value);
    for (var i = 0; i < tree.length; ++i) {
        var dir = tree[i];
        if (dir.users.indexOf(user) >= 0) {
            console.log("User '" + user + "' has access to directory '" + dir.name + "', which contains these files: " + dir.files.join(","));
        }
    }
}

getData();
```